# Handle optional function arguments

Tags: bash, aws-cloudformation

Trying to make a reusable function that can take up to 4 parameters (though the solution it should be arbitrary). I want to [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) these with parameters for AWS CloudFormation such that if I don't pass a positional argument to *update_stack* it won't get included in *CF_ARGS*.

```
##
# Update the stack with the given template
# @param: stack_name
# @param: template_body
# @param: [tags]
# @param: [parameters]
##
update_stack() {
    # Handle optional func parameters
    CF_PARAMS=("--stack-name" "--template-body" "--tags" "--parameters")
    # Only include a param if we have a value supplied as an argument. (+1 to ignore script name)
    CF_ARGS=($(for i in "${!CF_PARAMS[@]}"; do j=$(($i+1)); if [ -n "${!j}" ]; then echo "${CF_PARAMS[$i]} ${!j}"; fi; done))

    # Should make the call as "aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name $1 --template-body $2"
    # If $3 or $4 are not supplied then it should not add them to CFG_ARGS
    aws cloudformation create-stack "${CFG_ARGS[@]}"
}
```

I think I've got the *CF_ARGS* construction working as expected I just don't know how to [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) arguments in a bash function call and my google skills have failed on how to find a solution for this. Please help!

Thanks,
Alex

PS. The error I've getting from *awscli* is (maybe the double quotes?):

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --stack-name is required
```

EDIT (1):

Thanks @Barmar for your first solution. That got me to this error:

```
Unknown options: Description:, Handles, Authentication, &, Access, permissions, Resources:, ##, #, Policies, ##, PolicyDevelopers:, Type:, AWS::IAM::Policy, Properties:, PolicyName:, Developers-cf, #, @todo:, Remove, suffix, PolicyDocument:, Version:, "2012-10-17", Statement:, -, Effect:, Allow, NotAction:, -, iam:*, -, sts:AssumeRole, ...
```

The "--template-body" argument is a multi-line string (YAML file to be exact), is there anyway to double-quote each argument? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `CF_ARGS` to a single string, not an array. You need to wrap another set of parentheses around it to get an array.

```
CF_ARGS=($(for i in "${!CF_PARAMS[@]}"; do j=$(($i+1)); if [ -n "${!j}" ]; then echo "${CF_PARAMS[$i]} ${!j}"; fi; done))
```

And to make it treat each line of output from the `for` loop as a single argument, you can set `IFS` to only contain newline:

```
IFS=$'\n'
CF_ARGS=($(for i in "${!CF_PARAMS[@]}"; do j=$(($i+1)); if [ -n "${!j}" ]; then echo "${CF_PARAMS[$i]} ${!j}"; fi; done))
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for that, I've hit another problem though. I've updated the original question with a follow up, any suggestions?

Comment: I had to use `IFS=$";"` as the multiline string was splitting too but great idea! Still not fully working but will open a new question for the next bit :)

Comment: Hey @Barmar I've added another question for the next part of this problem, thanks for your help with this bit! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864168/call-bash-function-with-array-of-arguments-including-multiline-string

Comment: As an additional point. I ran into further problems downstream because I concatenated arguments together here: `"${CF_PARAMS[$i]} ${!j}"`. It should have actually been: `"${CF_PARAMS[$i]};${!j};"`. This results in 2 array items, not just 1 which when used as function arguments downstream make it possible to pass the array as function inputs.